# How to fix android media CursorLoader failed to detect media files in data folder

Tags: android, mediastore, android-cursorloader

I am using CursorLoader to get the media files from storage. It's working fine for internal and external storage except for the directory and sub-directory of *sdcard/android/data/*

for example, it fails to detect

```
sdcard/android/data/com.package.name/files/myFile.mp3
```

My code

```
String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA;

mCursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getContext(),
              MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                selection,
                null,
                null);
```

Comment: does any of those subfolders have `.nomedia` file inside?

Comment: @pskink inside the data folder, there is a .nomedia file. But the sub-directory doesn't have any

Comment: remove it and rescan your folder